# Ajuda para gravar em USUARIOS e AspNetUsers de uma vez só

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Ajuda por favor. Eu perdi todo meu dia refazendo várias partes do sistema, tentando um monte de soluções diferentes mas acabei sem idéias.

Tenho uma solução com várias aplicações. Uma dessas aplicações (onde tento isolar a persistência de dados) tenho o contexto criado com DataBase First no  Entity Framework. Obs.: Eu já tinha incluído na base de dados, com um script de create, as tabelas do Identity.

Em outra camada da minha solução adicionei uma aplicação MVC pura sem controle de usuário. Então adicionei via NuGet o Entity Framework e o Identity.

E finalmente criei ApplicationUser, IdentityDbContext e ApplicationRoleManager:

```
public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   [Display(Name = "Usuario", Description = "Identificação para Login")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "000027 - O Login não pode ser vazio ou nulo.")]
   [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "000028 - O Login pode ter no máximo 30 caracteres.")]
   [DuplicadoNaBase("AspNetUsersDao", "SelecionarPorLogin", ErrorMessage = "000031 - O Login informado já existe na base de dados.")]
   public string LOGIN { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   [Display(Name = "Senha", Description = "Senha para Login")]
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "000029 - A senha não pode ser vazia ou nula.")]
   [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "000030 - A senha pode ter no máximo 30 caracteres.")]
   [DataType(DataType.Password)]
   public string SENHA { get; set; }

   public virtual USUARIOS USUARIOS { get; set; }

   [NotMapped]
   public string Perfil { get; set; }
}

public class GPSdEntitiesIdentity : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   public GPSdEntitiesIdentity() : base("IdentityConnection")
   {
   }
}

public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<IdentityRole, string>
{
   public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string> roleStore)
    : base(roleStore)
   {
   }
   public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
   {
       return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new GPSdEntities()));
   }
}
```

Bom basicamente meu problema acontece porque já tinha uma base de dados com uma tabela USUARIO. Inicialmente tentei fundir minha tabela USUARIO com a AspNetUser. Mas não deu certo porque AspNetUser tem aquele GUID (string Id) e eu teria que refazer um monte de relacionamentos na base de dados. Então mantive as duas tabelas. Adicionei um IdAspNetUser na minha tabela USUARIOS e elas ficaram com um relacionamento 1 to 1.

Fiz uma View que trabalha com o ApplpicationUser para cadastrar o usuario e estava funcionando ok. Mas achei que estava estranho, por que eu estava fazendo 1 userManager.add e depois 1 ContextoPersistencia.USUARIOS.Add. Como o relacionamento entre elas é 1 to 1, tive então a brilhante ideia de adicionar no ApplicationUser uma propriedade virtual USUARIOS USUARIOS {get; set} e foi  aí que comecei a ter erros e a dar voltas.

Quando tento:

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new GPSdEntitiesIdentity()));
List<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers = new List<ApplicationUser>();
ApplicationUsers = userManager.Users.ToList();
```

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:
*System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException - 
"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
GPSd.Web.MVC.IdentityContext.AspNetUserLogins: : EntityType 'AspNetUserLogins' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType. AspNetUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'AspNetUserLogins' is based on type 'AspNetUserLogins' that has no keys defined."*

Se eu marco a propriedade Virtual USUARIOS dentro de ApplicationUser como [NotMapped], a aplicativo volta a funcionar, mas aí tenho que salvar o AspNetId e o USUARIO separadamente...

Estou tentando fazer algo simples como:

```
ApplicationUser identityUser = new ApplicationUser
{
   UserName = model.LOGIN,
   LOGIN = model.LOGIN,
   SENHA = model.SENHA,
   USUARIOS = model.USUARIOS
};
IdentityResult resultado = userManager.Create(identityUser, model.SENHA);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que vc poderia fazer o seguinte:
Mantém só a tabela de AspNetUsers e inclua as propriedades da sua tabela antiga ( 
Inclusive o ID, deixe ele como um campo Unique no banco de dados e usa ele pra fazer os joins e tudo mais).

Caso vc ñ queira fazer isso, considere isso: 
O EntityFramework entende uma propriedade virtual como algum tipo de relacionamento. Se vc define uma propriedade na classe ApplicationUser, na classe Usuários vc precida definir quem é a Foreign Key da tabela para ele fazer o mapeamento.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado Will. Realmente achei mais fácil manter uma única tabela. Achei um excelente tutorial que me ajudou inclusive a passar os Id's do Identity para Int. Fiz em uma aplicação teste e funcionou. Quando repliquei na minha aplicação de fato fico recebendo um erro 'The entity types 'CustomRole' and 'AspNetRoles' cannot share table 'AspNetRoles'. Fiz até outro post com essa dúvida: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257544/erro-the-entity-types-customrole-and-aspnetroles-cannot-share-table-aspnet