# Erro: The entity types 'CustomRole' and 'AspNetRoles' cannot share table 'AspNetRoles'

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Galera criei toda a estrutura o Identity para trabalhar com INT ao invés de GUID. Utilizando DataBase First e incluído na base de dados, com um script de create, as tabelas do Identity modificadas (apenas alterei AspNetUsers).

porém toda vez que chamo:

```
userManager.Users.ToList();
```

recebo o seguinte erro:

> The entity types 'CustomRole' and 'AspNetRoles' cannot share table 'AspNetRoles' because they are not in the same type hierarchy or do not have a valid one to one foreign key relationship with matching primary keys between them

Vou colocar alguns trechos do código a seguir... mas não entendo Meu CustonRole apenas herda IdentityRole e minha AspNetRoles está intocada igual que foi criada automaticamente no primeiro cadastro de usuario de uma aplicação de referencia. Inclusive tenho essa aplicação de referencia apontando para o mesmo banco e funcionando sem esse erro. Até onde sei as 2 (aplicação de referencia e minha aplicação oficial) estão com as configurações do Identity idênticas.

Entidade POCO gerada para AspNetRoles:

```
namespace EFBcoDadosSQL
{
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;

   public partial class AspNetRoles
   {
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public AspNetRoles()
    {
        this.AspNetUsers = new HashSet<AspNetUsers>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<AspNetUsers> AspNetUsers { get; set; }
}
}
```

Minha CustonRole para trabalhar com INT:

```
public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
{ 
   public CustomRole() { } 
   public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}
```

Minha RoleManager:

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<CustomRole, int>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<CustomRole, int> roleStore)
            : base(roleStore)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
        {
            return new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>(new GPSdEntitiesIdentity()));
        }
    }
```

Minha Identity Context e ApplicationUser:

```
public class CustonUsers : IdentityUser<int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<CustonUsers, int> manager)
    {
        // Observe que o authenticationType deve corresponder àquele definido em CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Adicionar declarações de usuário personalizado aqui
        return userIdentity;
    }
public string LOGIN { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("STATUS_REGISTROS")]
    public int IDSTATUSREGISTRO { get; set; }

    public virtual STATUS_REGISTROS STATUS_REGISTROS { get; set; }
}

public class GPSdEntitiesIdentity : IdentityDbContext<CustonUsers, CustomRole, int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    public GPSdEntitiesIdentity()
        : base("IdentityConnection")
    {
    }

    public static GPSdEntitiesIdentity Create()
    {
        return new GPSdEntitiesIdentity();
    }
    public virtual DbSet<STATUS_REGISTROS> STATUS_REGISTROS { get; set; }
}
```

Se precisarem de mais alguma informação é só pedir. Já estou quebrando a cabeça com essa configuração a dias... E só sugeri adotar o Entity e Identity porque seria mais simples que ADO puro. Mas tem sido muito mais complicado

Obs: Fiz seguindo estes excelentes tutoriais:
https://danieleagle.com/2014/05/setting-up-asp-net-identity-framework-2-0-with-database-first-vs2013-update-2-spa-template/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity

Comment: Amigo, veja se esse video não lhe ajuda https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dWmT9R_ZthY

Comment: Vi lá e essa parte de passar para int fiz o mesmo que ele, com a diferença de que trabalhei com databasefirst.

Comment: @PabloTondolodeVargas descobri que o problema é um pouco diferente do que eu pensava... Parece que há um conflito entre as tabelas do Identity e as tabelas do meu contexto. Expliquei melhor aqui:https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/257634/erro-quando-identitydbcontext-usa-entidades-edmx-do-contexto-geral